# Is processes in Docker container will be shown as same process on Host OS?

Tags: image, docker, process, containers

I'm running a Mongo container in `Docker` on my Macbook. And to show the processes in that particular container, we use `TOP` command as shown below.[image]

From some tutorial videos on Udemy, the lecturer shown that the process shown in above image with `PID` 3238 is showing as processes in Host as well by command `ps aux`.

However, I couldnt find process with `PID` 3238 under the list of processes on my host. Wondering if I setup the Docker wrongly or I've missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Docker container` has different PID namespace from host OS by default.

In order to share PID namespace with Host OS, you should use `host pid mode`.

For example,

```
$ docker run --rm --pid=host -it ubuntu:16.04 top
```

The command shows all processes of the host OS including the `top` process in the `container` and you can also find the same PID between the `top` process in the `container` and `top` process in the host OS.

For docker-compose is [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#pid).